# How to convert UTC offset written like this "UTC+02:00" to timestamp format?

Tags: javascript

How to convert UTC offset like this for example "UTC+02:00" to timestamp format (offset written in milliseconds)? I need to read the offset written in such way in the json file and then convert it to minutes

Comment: What is the timestamp format?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and the format you're trying to get, saying specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Time written in milliseconds

Comment: Split the UTC offset in hours and minutes and then: `milliseconds = ((hours * 60 + minutes) * 60) * 1000`. You can use a regular expression to split the string `/UTC([+-]\d{2}):(\d{2})/`

Comment: Yeah, but e.g. Kathmandu has a timezone +5:45. So it will be more complicated and I thought that maybe is simplest way to do it

Comment: The code I posted in my comment also works for `UTC+05:45`

Comment: OK, I will check it. THX then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the values with a regular expression

```
/UTC([+-]\d{2}):(\d{2})/
```

and calculate the offset in milliseconds with

```
milliseconds = ((hours * 60 + minutes) * 60) * 1000
```

Example:

```js
const [hours, minutes] = 'UTC-05:45'.match(/UTC([+-]\d{2}):(\d{2})/).slice(1).map(Number);

const milliseconds = Math.sign(hours) * ((Math.abs(hours) * 60 + minutes) * 60) * 1000

console.log(milliseconds);
```

Comment: This helped me, although it is necessary to make a condition for a negative offset e.g. "UTC-01: 30". But that is not a big problem anymore. Thx

Comment: @RobertW Yes, I fixed the code.